# Backbone + RequireJS "define is not defined"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, concatenation, minify

I have a fairly large project in which I'm trying to concatenate all my JS files into one file. I've been able to do just this, but I'm having trouble actually implementing the two files into the code.

My Gruntfile has a task for doing the concatenation:

```
requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    baseUrl: "<%= yeoman.app %>",
                    mainConfigFile: "<%= yeoman.app %>/config.js",
                    include: ["config"],
                    out: "<%= yeoman.app %>/dist/main.js"
                }
            }
        },
```

Again, this works just fine. My config.js contains all the libraries, models, helpers, collections, and views used in the project:

```
   require.config({
            paths: {
                // path configuration assumes .js suffix

                // Libraries
                'jquery': 'js/libs/jquery-1.8.2.min',
                // custom version of jQM, see comments section in library for custom change log
                'jQM': 'js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-CUSTOM',
                //'jQUI': 'js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.24.dev.min',
                'Underscore': 'js/libs/underscore',
                'JSON2': 'js/libs/json2',
                'Backbone': 'js/libs/backbone',
        etc...
        },
        shim: {
            'jQMConfig': {
                //deps: ['jQUI'] // use jQUI as dependency if jQUI is required.  see https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5119
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'jQM': {
                deps: ['jQMConfig']
            },
etc...
    });
require(['js/router']);
```

Finally, in my HTML code I'm including these two scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main.js"></script>
<script data-main="config" src="js/libs/require-2.1.15.min.js"></script>
```

which is where I'm getting the error in the console "define is not defined" and all the files in the js/ folder are still being called. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `require.js` file first, meanwhile you can specify `data-main` to be your main file.

Include the scripts in your html like this:

```
<script data-main="dist/main" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
```

See [patterns for seperating config from main module](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module), for more details.

Comment: AH, thank you so much. I was stuck on that for hours. Didn't even look into the data-main attribute